# asp.net mvc3 formauthentication,custom role provider-Jquery auto load tabs not working..

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui, asp.net-membership, jquery-tabs, roleprovider

I am creating dynamically loading tabs using jquery Ui tabs in my ASP.NET mvc3 project.

Here i have a product page. The product page contains left menus like Customer,Address,Contact,etc..

Here my process is when i click one my left menus, the tab created dynamically with Grid records.

And,

I'm creating a custom role provider and I set a Authorize attribute specifying a role in my controller and it's working just fine, like this:

[Authorize(Roles="SuperAdmin")]
public class SuperAdminController : Controller
...

If one user doens't have access to this controller, And click one of my left menu means,
he's redirected to login page. Its also working fine.

The problem is after the user logged in it didn't redirect the proper page in tab content area.

If my problem not understandable means please let me know..

Thanks Advance...

Comment: It does not redirect to correct page or correct page but not the correct tab?

Comment: Are you using AJAX to load the contents of the tabs?

Comment: Also, how are you redirecting? With the default login post action provided by MVC3 template in visual studio?

Comment: @Mohayemin you are right, i am redirected the default login post action provided by mvc3. Like this, in web.config                          <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>

Comment: @Darin-Thanks for response me. Yes i am using AJAX to load contents of the tab

Comment: @Mohayemin-Thanks for response me. the think is i want to load the content part after logged in. If i am not set [Authorize(Roles="SuperAdmin")] like that the content area loading fine using ajax load.

Answer (score 0):

If you carefully check the URL in the browser, you will see that the URL does not change when you load something by Ajax. That is the point of Ajax actually, you do not load the whole page, right?

Now as the state is not saved when you try to load the content using Ajax, your redirect URL is only the page you loaded initially. That is why you cannot go back to the tab you wanted to load.

Comment: @Mohayemin- Actually what happened means, when i click the left menu, the auto-loading tabs function hit and return default login page using Ajax. So after i logged in, how can i call same Ajax function to load content part.

Comment: Ok, so you are loading the login page by ajax too?

Comment: What do you see in the content area when you login and then redirected?

Comment: Not only a content area whole page was blank screen. But the address bar look change.